# Joomla Menu to display only current (root) menu subitems

Tags: joomla, menu

I'm rather new to Joomla. Here is what I want.

Say I have a menu with two root items named "1" and "2".
"1" has 1a and 1b subitems and "2" has 2a and 2b subitems.

What I want is when on page "2" to have a module which will only display 2a and 2b menu subitems (without 1a and 1b).

Is there an easy way to do it without 1 been a category of 1a and 1b and 2 been a category of 2a and 2b?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That is not so difficult. Even with core you can manage and no need for any 3rd party extension also.
Steps:

1. First Create all the menu and submenu items in the main menu where you want.
2. Then Create another 2 menus not menu items; like menu for 1a and 1b and another menu for 2a and 2b.
3. Go to main menu and select the menu under 1 i.e 1a and 1b and then click on batch. You will get option to copy the submenu items to new menu 1. Similarly do for 2 also.
4. Now the menus are created. Next create two modules one for submenu 1a and 1b and another for submenu 2a and 2b.
5. In modules you will find Menu Assignment Tab, there you Chose `only on the Page selected`. Next you will find page 1 where you want 1 a and 1b to display. Select that alone. therefore in other pages it wont show. Similar procedure you follow for 2.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I know how to do it manually. What I want is Joomla to do it in kind of auto mode.. to have just one module which will be displayed at all rootmenu pages and will display only this active rootmenu page sublinks. Definitely not to duplicate modules and menus.